# Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type Guid - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Wing]
(
    [Id]                    [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Wing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Id])
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Wing__Id] DEFAULT (newid()),
    [Name]                  [NVARCHAR](50) NULL
)
```

I have set up the the model builder in Entity Framework as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Wing>(
entity =>
{
entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

//Start of Id
entity.Property(e => e.Id) 
  .HasColumnName("Id")
  .HasColumnType(typeof(Guid).Name);
//End of Id

entity.Property(e => e.Name)
  .HasColumnName("Name")
  .HasColumnType(typeof(string).Name);
});
```

Now, when I try to add a new Wing, I set up the value like:

```
Wing wing = new Wing() {Name = "Wing 1"};
```

And I add it to the database using

```
await dbContext.Set<Wing>().AddAsync(wing);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When I add a single Wing this way, it work as expected without errors.
When I add multiple wings using the following code:

```
List<Wing> wings = new List<Wing>();
wings.Add(new Wing() {Name = "Wing 1"});
wings.Add(new Wing() {Name = "Wing 2"});
await dbContext.Set<Wing>().AddRangeAsync(wings);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get the following error:

```
     Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type Guid
```

However, when I comment out the code for binding "Id" in the model builder, everything works as expected without any exceptions.

Can someone help me with the root cause or a resolution? I am stumped because similar tables work just fine with or without the model builder for the "Id" column.

Answer (score 1):

HasColumnType refers to database types, not .NET types.  So it should be “UNIQUEIDENTIFIER”.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will test this. But, how does SaveChanges work for one entity and not for multiple entities if the data type supposedly does not match?